Sharing space across encrypted/non-encrypted AFPS volumes
According to Apple's support documentation,

Apple File System (APFS) allocates disk space on demand. When a single APFS container (partition) has multiple volumes, the container’s free space is shared and can be allocated to any of the individual volumes as needed

I can find nothing about a regular AFPS volume sharing space with an encrypted one, however. Are there security implications for this shared space?

I assume it can leak some metadata, for example, how much space is used in the encrypted volume.

An APFS container can have both non-encrypted and encrypted volumes at the same time.  An APFS volume can have both non-encrypted and encrypted files and folders at the same time. IFAIK, there are no more security implications for shared space over files and folders than over volumes.
